# Как спарсить строку в массив ArrayList с помощью GSON?

Tags: android, массивы, json, gson

Есть такой json, который парсится из файла:

```
[{
    "cachedFsi": -2,
    "cachedSsi": -2,
    "scheme": "NOT CACHED",
    "uriString": "/data/user/0/ru.yandex.matu1.toddlersbook/files/bookcover_1.jpg",
    "host": "NOT CACHED",
    "port": -2
}, {
    "cachedFsi": -2,
    "cachedSsi": -2,
    "scheme": "NOT CACHED",
    "uriString": "/data/user/0/ru.yandex.matu1.toddlersbook/files/bookcover_2.jpg",
    "host": "NOT CACHED",
    "port": -2
}, {
    "cachedFsi": -2,
    "cachedSsi": -2,
    "scheme": "NOT CACHED",
    "uriString": "/data/user/0/ru.yandex.matu1.toddlersbook/files/bookcover_3.jpg",
    "host": "NOT CACHED",
    "port": -2
}, {
    "cachedFsi": -2,
    "cachedSsi": -2,
    "scheme": "NOT CACHED",
    "uriString": "/data/user/0/ru.yandex.matu1.toddlersbook/files/bookcover_4.jpg",
    "host": "NOT CACHED",
    "port": -2
}, {
    "cachedFsi": -2,
    "cachedSsi": -2,
    "scheme": "NOT CACHED",
    "uriString": "/data/user/0/ru.yandex.matu1.toddlersbook/files/bookcover_5.jpg",
    "host": "NOT CACHED",
    "port": -2
}, {
    "cachedFsi": -2,
    "cachedSsi": -2,
    "scheme": "NOT CACHED",
    "uriString": "/data/user/0/ru.yandex.matu1.toddlersbook/files/bookcover_6.jpg",
    "host": "NOT CACHED",
    "port": -2
}]
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как из этой строки выдернуть uriString и записать в массив ArrayList?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    JSONArray rootJSON = new JSONArray(new JSONTokener(Твой String с Json));
    for (int i = 0; i < rootJSON.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject o = rootJSON.getJSONObject(i);
        list.add(o.getString("uriString"));
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Библиотека `gson` открывает широкие возможности для преобразования json-строк в java-объекты.

**1-й способ.**

Для того чтобы вытащить из json-строки то, что нам нужно, можно написать собственный конвертер, реализующий интерфейс `JsonDeserializer<T>`, где `T` - тип объекта, который мы хотим получить.
Вот пример такого конвертера:

```
public class JsonConverter implements JsonDeserializer<ArrayList<String>> {


    // Указываем правила, по которым преобразуем json в нужный нам объект.
    @Override
    public ArrayList<String> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonArray array = json.getAsJsonArray();
        ArrayList<String> listOfUriStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (JsonElement element : array) {
            String uriString = element.getAsJsonObject().get("uriString").getAsString();
            listOfUriStrings.add(uriString);
        }
        return listOfUriStrings;
    }

    // Получаем из json-строки список
    public ArrayList<String> getListFromJSON(String json) {
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        // import java.lang.reflect.Type;
        Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>(){}.getType();
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(listType, new JsonConverter());
        final Gson gson = builder.create();
        return gson.fromJson(json, listType);
    }
}
```

Тогда получить нужный нам список можно, применив к объекту класса `JsonConverter` метод `getListFromJSON`, передав в него json-строку:

```
JsonConverter converter = new JsonConverter();
ArrayList<String> listOfUriStrings = converter.getListFromJSON(json);
```

**2-й способ.**

Библиотека json умеет самостоятельно определять, как нужно преобразовывать json-строку в объект. Поэтому зачастую удобно создать класс, объект которого или массив объектов будет отождествляться с json-строкой и автоматически в неё сериализовываться или десериализовываться из неё. Для создания такого класса удобно пользоваться сайтом http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/. 
Наш класс описывает один элемент из json-массива. Также опишем в этом классе статический метод, который будет по json-строке создавать список объектов этого класса.

```
public class JsonData {
    @SerializedName("cachedFsi")
    @Expose
    private int cachedFsi;
    @SerializedName("cachedSsi")
    @Expose
    private int cachedSsi;
    @SerializedName("scheme")
    @Expose
    private String scheme;
    @SerializedName("uriString")
    @Expose
    private String uriString;
    @SerializedName("host")
    @Expose
    private String host;
    @SerializedName("port")
    @Expose
    private int port;

    public int getCachedFsi() {
        return cachedFsi;
    }

    public void setCachedFsi(int cachedFsi) {
        this.cachedFsi = cachedFsi;
    }

    public int getCachedSsi() {
        return cachedSsi;
    }

    public void setCachedSsi(int cachedSsi) {
        this.cachedSsi = cachedSsi;
    }

    public String getScheme() {
        return scheme;
    }

    public void setScheme(String scheme) {
        this.scheme = scheme;
    }

    public String getUriString() {
        return uriString;
    }

    public void setUriString(String uriString) {
        this.uriString = uriString;
    }

    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }

    public void setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }


    public static ArrayList<JsonData> getListFromJSON(String json) {
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = builder.create();
        // import java.lang.reflect.Type;
        Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<JsonData>>() {}.getType();
        ArrayList<JsonData> list = gson.fromJson(json, listType);
        return list;
    }

}
```

Тогда воспользоваться этим методом можно очень просто:

```
ArrayList<JsonData> list = JsonData.getListFromJSON(json);
```

Если же вам нужны только строки `"uriString"`, можно просто убрать все остальные атрибуты и методы из этого класса. Ну, и назвать этот класс, например, `UriString`.

```
public class UriString {

    @SerializedName("uriString")
    @Expose
    private String uriString;


    public String getUriString() {
        return uriString;
    }

    public void setUriString(String uriString) {
        this.uriString = uriString;
    }


    public static ArrayList<UriString> getListFromJSON(String json) {
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = builder.create();
        // import java.lang.reflect.Type;
        Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<UriString>>() {}.getType();
        ArrayList<UriString> list = gson.fromJson(json, listType);
        return list;
    }

}
```

Соответственно:

```
ArrayList<UriString> list = UriString.getListFromJSON(json);
```